# Could not load file or assembly X or one of its dependencies. There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)

Tags: asp.net, exception

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run my website on developement (all in localhost).
I do have plenty of space on both disks, and yesterday was working just fine. This is the first time I see something like this, I don't know where to start...

I have checked:

- The DLL is in the bin folder, just as normal
- There's enough space in C: (about 40GB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after lots of researching, I didn't find an answer to my problem on here or anywhere of the internet.

I didn't mention that my site makes requests to a service in an external server (even from localhost). Apparently, my problem was that one dll in this server was corrupt for some reason (couldn't find exactly why), and that was giving the error. The minute I replaced it with a copy of itself I had working somewhere else, everything began working again.

This has nothing to do with having enough space on the disk, so if anyone comes across this error note that it might not be an space problem.

I just don't know why did I get this error, but I'm posting this just in case someone finds this error and can't figure it out or isn't what it seems to be.

Comment: This was my exact problem! Thanks! just re copied dll's